# How to cut the first field in powershell which is in double quotes

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have some data in my variable, so how to cut the first field and get the output as second field in powershell.

PS D:\Testing_PowerShell_Script> $content    (Displaying the variable content)

```
"title": "myname",
"title": "othername",
```

(This is the data which variable of content having.)

Now I want to cut the "title": filed and get the output as only myname instead of double quotes and commas in powershell. Please help on this

Comment: For your input, following would do `Testing_Powershell_Script | % {($_ -split '"')[3]}`

Comment: This looks like it is was originally in JSON format.  If so, you might find it easier to convert the data first with [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6), rather than try to manipulate small snippets like this.

Comment: No problem but do read @boxdog's comment!

Comment: @Lieven. I can able to get second field without double quotes..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regex pattern with `Select-String` to grab everything in quotes following `"title":`:

```
$titles = $content |Select-String '"title": "([^"]+)"' -AllMatches |Select-Object -Expand Matches |ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

`$titles` is now an array of two strings `myname` and `othername`

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can directly get list of values without quotes

```
$t = '"title": "myname",
"qqqq": "othername",'
$t -split "," | %{ ($_ -split ":")[1] -replace "`"","" }
```